# How Do I Prevent User Profile Removal @ Sign in Screen : Chrome Enterprise

Tags: chrome-os

Chromebook with Enterprise Upgrade:

On the sign in screen I can select a drop down arrow next to a user name and "remove the account" from the Chromebook EVEN THOUGH I'M NOT SIGNED IN.

Please tell me I'm missing an Admin Panel security setting that can override this totally insane default.

POTENTIAL SCENARIO: Go to Starbucks. Order coffee. Sign out. Go to men's room, and my 8 year old (or some joker) blasts my user account from the Chromebook without even being signed in to the box! What? Really? No big deal you say, it's a cloud first device. Well, I have a VPN client that just got blasted. Now I'm screwed. I'm locked out of the corporate network. There are likely other horrible scenarios, but I'm new to this platform. You get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK there is a workaround to prevent this insane default behavior though Google does not encourage the workaround (even though a bug was filed years ago and users are screaming for a fix.) The workaround is **Never show user names and photos**

From the [docs](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/1375678#show_user_names):

> Sign-in screen
>
> Specifies whether the Chrome device's sign-in screen displays the
> names and pictures of users who have signed in to the device.
>
> Displaying the names and pictures of users on the sign-in screen
> allows users to quickly start their sessions and works best for most
> deployments. We recommend you change this setting rarely and
> selectively to ensure the best user experience.
>
> - **Always show user names and photos**—Lets users choose their user account
>   on the sign-in screen (default).
> - **Never show user names and
>   photos**—Prevents user accounts from being displayed on the sign-in
>   screen. Users must enter their Google Account username and password
>   each time they sign in to their Chrome device. If you have SAML single
>   sign-on (SSO) for Chrome devices and send users directly to the SAML
>   identity provider (IdP) page, Google redirects them to the SSO sign-in
>   page without entering their email address.
>
>   **Note**: If users are enrolled in 2-Step Verification, they’re prompted
>   to perform their second verification step each time they sign in to
>   their Chrome device.